# Why do some people write the indefinite article "a" before vowels?

Tags: grammar, indefinite-articles

According to the rule, the article "a" is for consonants and the article "an" is for vowels. Nevertheless, I have seen it frequently that many use the article "a" with both vowels and consonants. For example, they say "this is a expensive car" not "this is an expensive car" as it should be.
Is there a reason for that?

Comment: *'This is a expensive car'* is ungrammatical. It should be *this is **an** expensive car*.

Comment: If it's strictly a matter of writing, it's just a mistake. Many people make typos, especially when writing instead of typing. I have occasionally heard this, but very rarely, and either as a speech error or as an unsuccessful attempt to sound dialectal.

Comment: Yes, KannE. (English spellings are irregular and weird).

Comment: The decision is not based on vowel or consonant, it's based on the *sound* -- vowel sound or consonant sound.  Thus "*an* heir to the family fortune".

Comment: In the 'London Multicultural' regional dialect, and certain others (e.g. Caribbean), the conventions about 'an' (and the way 'the' is said) before words starting with a vowel sound) are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

It's *an* expensive car.

As Kann says, it's about the sound, not the type of letter. For instance, we say *a* uniform and *an* honor.

It's simply easier to say *an apple* than *a apple*. Likewise, it's easier to say *a uniform* than *an uniform*.

(Americans say *an herb*, while Brits say *a herb*. Can you guess why?)

Comment: In BrE, 'herb' starts with /h/ sound.
In AmE, 'herb' starts with a vowel.

Comment: Brits used to say 'an hotel', and I don't mean Cockneys.

Comment: I know all about that sound case like you said (hotel, euro, European, honor, herb, hour......etc.) But what would make someone use 'an' before words like expensive or old? Is it something colloquial?

Comment: @Yoanna - an apple, an expensive apple. The rule applies to whatever word is after the indefinite article.

Comment: I am sorry I meant "why would someone use 'a' not 'an' before expensive" but i got your point. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: As you guessed, it is colloquial or regional dialect.